# matplotlib: make a pie chart for select column in Python

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

Dataset:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/v9gmgxupkypn5dw/train-data.csv

I want to make a pie chart for Fuel_Type.
Divide the Fuel_Type into three part: Diesel, Petrol, and Others (not Diesel and Petrol).
Make a pie chart for that and show the percentages on that chart.

My codes are below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('car_train_data.csv',sep= ",",index_col= 0)


temp = car_df.groupby("Fuel_Type", as_index=False).size()
cutoff = temp["size"].sum() * 0.05
temp_idx = temp["size"] < cutoff
other_sum = temp.loc[temp_idx, "size"].sum()
```

But I really confused about how to define not Diesel and Petrol...Anyone can help me? Or show me a example so that I can change the code from other example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your dataframe based on the desired value for a specific column. Try something like:

```
petrol = df[df['Fuel_Type'] == 'Petrol']
diesel = df[df['Fuel_Type'] == 'Diesel']
others = df[df['Fuel_Type'] != 'Petrol' & df['Fuel_Type'] != 'Diesel']
```

this will create the three portions you need, then pass them to the pie chart